# apache maven version shown different than one installed

Tags: apache, maven

I have installed maven 2.2.1 and tested mvn -v command. But it shows maven version 2.0.11. (i had previously installed it and co-exist with 2.2.1) Why this?

Comment: It's because you still have 2.0.11 installed.

Comment: Look at your PATH. Or, maybe M2_HOME env vars.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the two following environment variables point to your 2.2.1 installation:

- M2_HOME
- PATH (pointing to %M2_HOME%/bin)

The output of mvn -v uses the M2_HOME environment variable, but keeping PATH and M2_HOME in line is important too.